# trailing slash htaccess for protect admin directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, trailing-slash

I called domain.net/about-us coming domain.net/about-us/ ( add trailin slash ) correct page !

I called domain.net/admin or domain.net/admin/ , the error is 404

When I added this line comments

```
#RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

coming up and asking for a password admin folder.

But i called domain.net/about-us ( don't trailing slash) coming 404

Waiting for your help, Thanks.

Murat

my root htaccess file :

```
...
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

#add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
...
RewriteRule ^about-us/$ index.php?p=cont&sef=about-us [L,NC]
...
```

admin folder (protect) htaccess file :

```
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/xxxxxxx/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give these configuration directives a test:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /index.php?p=cont&sef=about-us [L,NC]

# try to add this rule
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /$1/$2/ [R]
```

Comment: Thanks Servant,
i try your  code,
Coming up and asking for a password admin folder.
But i called domain.net/about-us ( don't trailing slash) coming 404

Comment: @user2263249 Would you please link here you site? I'd just tried to redirect */$var* into */$var/*. Is the folder */admin/* ask you a password even if */$var* didn't redirecting into */$var/*?

Comment: @user2263249 I'd tried to go to */admin/* and even to */admin* but they're redirecting me into */404.php* page. Now where's the page that's asking for a password?

Comment: sorry, now changed 
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

to 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /$1/ [R]

try again please

Comment: Ok, i check again. Thanks Servant